# Featured Post Fall back Image not working for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a fallback image for my wordpress posts but it's not working, I'm refraining from using plugins due the reason that plugins makes the website heavy. So I'm hard coding it,

Here's my code and it's not working

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail_url() } else { echo do_shortcode('[theme]')  echo '/images/fixbanner.jpg' }?>
```

I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Anyone please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Forgot to close it :D

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail_url(); } else { echo do_shortcode('[theme]'); echo ('/images/fixbanner.jpg'); }?>
```